# Instance methods not in scope of JS module in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, module, scope

I'm trying to create a non-singleton object in NodeJS but when calling internal instance methods within the object, they are "undefined".

```
// We auto-refresh the cached data every 'refreshInterval' milliseconds
var refreshInterval = 30*1000;
var refreshTimer = null;
// We stop refreshing 'idleTimeout' milliseconds after the last request for our data
var idleTimeout = 5 * 60 * 1000;    // 5 minutes
var idleTimer = null;

var cachedData = null;
var queryCallback = null;

function Cache(options) {
  if (options) {
    this.refreshInterval = options.refreshInterval || 30;
    this.queryCallback = options.queryCallback || null;
    this.idleTimeout = options.idleTimeout || 5 * 60 * 1000;
  }
}

Cache.prototype.data = function(callback) {
  updateIdle();
  if (cachedData) {
    callback(cachedData);
  } else {
    queryData(function(newdata) {
      callback(newdata);
    });
  }
}

Cache.prototype.updateIdle = function() {
  idleTimer && clearTimeout(idleTimer);
  idleTimer = setTimeout(haltRefresh, idleTimeout);
  wslog.info(`Will cease cache refresh at ${new Date(Date.now() + idleTimeout)} if no new activity`);
}

// ...

module.exports = Cache;
```

When I create the object

```
var Cache = require('./cache.js');
var myCache = Cache(opts);
```

It works but when I invoke `myCache.data()`, the invocation of the internal method `updateIdle()` halts the app because *ReferenceError: updateIdle is not defined*

Something tells me NONE of my instance methods are going to be "defined" even though they plainly are. And before I made them `prototype` methods, they worked fine. These would be a valid Java instance method invocations - is there some scope issue with JS?

Should I remove the `Cache.prototype.` from the functions I don't need exposed and then just use them?  Do I have to add `this.` to any instance method invocations?

What do I need to know to make JS "just work" like normal OOP?

Comment: Properties never come into scope. You always have to call methods as methods of an object, i.e. `this.updateIdle()` etc

Comment: I am updating every single reference to an internal function or variable to include a `this.` but I honestly cannot remember *ever* seeing this in the wild so I feel it's still "wrong" somehow...

Comment: It's *always* been the case in JavaScript. Either they weren't object methods, or you were looking at a different language such as Java.

Comment: Now my iVar properties `var cachedData` are undefined. This is so miserably hard.

Comment: `var cachedData` is not a property of the individual `Cache` instance object, it's a module-level static variable that you initialise to `null` and never update (at least in the code you've shown)

Comment: So I have to move all my variable declarations into the Cache() function and then they'll be accessible within other prototype methods?  [EDIT: Nope, tried this, the values are still undefined. The whole point of an object is "data and methods that operate on that data" - how can I define data that the methods cal all see?]

Comment: PS: I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Define a property, like you did with `this.refreshInterval` and the other two. `var` always declares a local variable, never an object property.

Comment: Oh, so in my code, I have 2 properties called `refreshInterval` - a local var (at the top of the file, never used) and an object property (duck-typed inside the constructor).